# Navigation pane expand below when "link" clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I really like the `div` accordion effect, I use it a lot for site organization and navigation, but I want to try and use it for a horizontal navigation pane rather than for a vertical list.

[image: example]

The "clickables" pane has more than one link, and when any of the links are clicked, it expands below to show more links. So if I click link A, it will expand to show links A.A, A.B, A.C, etc; if I click link B, it will do the same for links B.A, B.B, etc. I want the lower pane to be dynamic and display links relevant to the link I clicked in the clickables pane as seen in the image. I use the word "link" loosely; in the links pane they are indeed hyperlinks, but in the clickables pane they're just clickable words that do things onclick.

How can I go about doing this? I had initially tried AJAX accordion but the spacing is all wrong. I'm not too well versed enough in AJAX or jQuery to make it work the way I want, so I hope hoping there was some tips on how to do it.

Here's some makeshift HTML illustrating what I would like to accomplish.

```
<div id="navigation">
    <span id="A">Expand A</span> &nbsp; 
    <span id="B">Expand B</span>
</div>
//if "Expand A" is clicked, display the below
<div id="expandedA">
    <a href="./link1.php">Link 1</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="./link2.php">Link 2</a>
</div>
//if "Expand B" is clicked, display the below
<div id="expandedB">
    <a href="./link3.php">Link 3</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="./link4.php">Link 4</a>
</div>
```

`expandedA` and `expandedB` would have the same width as `navigation`, and they would expand below `navigation`. Something similar to accordion, but I think I need to modify it such that both spans have the same dropdown.

Comment: You should post relevant HTML code too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a javascript function that uses innerHTML.

For example:

```
function clickable(){
    document.getElementById('clickable').innerHTML = "content";
}
```

Use onClick to call it

```
<div id="click" onClick="javascript:clickable();">Click me!</div>
```

It's easier to explain with a js fiddle

JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rJ3KS/

Edit: I think this is what you want: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rJ3KS/1/

Comment: Cheers. I've used your JSFiddle and changed it a bit to better show what I meant. http://jsfiddle.net/T9LdT/1/ This works, but I'm not sure how to make them also collapse when reclicked or another category is clicked. There's also a lot of redundant code: what if I have 50+ clickables? This would equate to a couple hundred lines of code, all of it reused with minor adjustments. edit; just caught your edit, this is exactly what I need, although it lacks a little finesse (what if message contains several lines of HTML?).

Comment: No problem. It can still be a problem with the several lines of HTML, but in the case of simple links and such, it shouldn't be too much of an issue.